# Selenium java file download not working on Chrome ver 75

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue with download file from Google chrome version `75.0.3770.80` with Selenium Java, it displays Failed - Download Error

I've tried to change the download path and then download the file, the path does get set but no luck.

[image]

**Below is sample code** :

```
WebDriver webDriver;

  System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver",
          SetObjectProperties.appConfig.
          getPropertyValue ("ChromeDriver"));
String currentDir = System.getProperty ("user.dir");
String downloadpath = currentDir + "/" + "Download";

  HashMap < String, Object > chromePrefs =
  new HashMap < String, Object > ();
  chromePrefs.put ("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
  chromePrefs.put ("download.prompt_for_download", false);
  chromePrefs.put ("download.default_directory", downloadpath);
  chromePrefs.
  put
  ("profile.content_settings.exceptions.automatic_downloads.*.setting",
   1);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions ();
  options.setExperimentalOption ("prefs", chromePrefs);
  options.addArguments ("--incognito");
  webDriver = new ChromeDriver (options);
  webDriver.manage ().window ().maximize ();
  webDriver.get ("http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
  webDriver.findElement (By.linkText ("32 bit Windows IE")).click ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running on windows try this it worked for me.

```
String downloadpath = currentDir + "\\" + "Download";
```

Comment: Thanks @sras, It is the same - The download.default_directory is being set by the string filepath which I am passing (checked that in settings while debugging), the Issue is download doesn't start at all

Answer (score 1):

Try setting downloadpath as below:

String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+**File.separator**+"Download";

Comment: Could you explain why would this change fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this line removed

```
chromePrefs.put ("download.default_directory", downloadpath);
```

Comment: Thank you!
Setting preferences with the above line works as the path for download get sets by it however the download doesn't start as can be seen over the screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear. I meant that if you do not set download.default_directory and let it default then it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Need to try above however currently I've downgraded to an older version and it works fine but the thing is we need to set download path to the current repo.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue which is resolve by using below solution :-

```
            String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

            String downloadpath = currentDir + "/" + "Download";

            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadpath);
```